# SQL Server Replication - Publication and Subscriber schema differ, need to sync

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a SQL Server 2005 database where the publication and subscriber schema are different. This was intentionally done by turning the "Replicate Schema" option to False.

However I now need to propagate the publication schema to the subscriber.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Visual Studio's Schema Comparison tool, or some third party equivalent; it will visually show you what's different and optionally create a script to sync them. Just beware that depending on the change, it may try to copy the table to a work table and then drop the source and rename the new table, which will fail if the table is replicated.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way of achieving this?

The best way is to script out replication and edit the scripts.

```
exec sp_addarticle ...
         ,@destination_table = N'Your_Subscriber_TableName'
         , @destination_owner = N'NewSchema'
```

Then run the snapshot agent and the log reader agent to sync data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't necessarily know what schema has been changed. I need to identify this first. Also any reason why script vs gui? I find the gui much more reliable than the generate scripts function for replication.

Comment: You have to find out by comparing Publisher and schema objects that are currently replicated. I prefer T-SQL as it has more options than GUI and is very useful if you have to automate it .